# Counting : How many combinations are possible in a sorted set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a set of n elements, where each element can be any of $ \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} $ how many different combinations are possible. Note that all elements are sorted i.e. $\{3,2\}$ is the same as $\{2,3\}$ and each element can only be used once.

For instance, without the sorting requirement:

if $ n$ were $5$, then the number of different combinations would be $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6$

but i cannot get my mind wrapped around removing the symmetrical entries.

Comment: You want to look at combinations [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination], if order matters you are considering permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a set of $n$ elements and you want to choose $k$ of those elements in the way you described. Then the number of all possible combinations is 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}$$
if $0 \leq k \leq n$.

The reasoning behind it is this: As you have already realized, if we differentiate between $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$, then we have 
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$
possible combinations, because for the first position we have $n$ elements to choose from, for the second position $n-1$ and so on.

Now if we identify $(3,2)$ with $(2,3)$, we do the following: Suppose that $k$ elements have already been chosen. Then there are $k!$ possible ways to arrange those elements. Hence, if $C$ is the number of combinations to choose $k$ elements out of $n$ without considering their order, we get
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = C \cdot k!$$
as we first choose the elements and afterwards their order. It follows that
$$C = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} = \binom{n}{k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- You want to know the number of subsets
- Each of the ten elements either is or is not in a particular subset
- Consider whether the empty set counts as a possibility
- Calculate the number of possibilities if you had started with a smaller set such as $\{0\}$, $\{0,1\}$, or $\{0,1,2\}$ and see if you can spot a pattern